# Spring: Create a JsonSerializer with @Autowired field

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Solution 1: As my TextSerializer class contains @Autowired field, it must not be created with `new` operator. It must be retrieved from Spring container. But field `textSerializer` in my `JacksonMapper` class is null.

Solution 2: If i create `textSerializer` with `new` operator, then `sessionFactory` inside is null.

I think that solution 1 is more right and problem is in `JsonVisitable` interface. But my `textSerializer` field don't want autowire, if it's type will be class(`TextSerializer` or `JsonSerializer`).

```
        public class JacksonMapper extends ObjectMapper {


            @Autowired
            private JsonFormatVisitable textSerializer;

            public JacksonMapper() {
                SimpleModule module=new SimpleModule("SimpleModule");
                module.addSerializer(Text.class, (JsonSerializer<Object>) textSerializer);
              ..............................
                registerModule(module);
            }
        }


        public class TextSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Text> {

            @Autowired
            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            @Override
            @Transactional
            public void serialize(Text value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                .........
            }
        }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan({"xxx.service", "xxx.controller" })
    public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

.........................
        @Bean
        public JacksonMapper jacksonMapper(){
            return new JacksonMapper();
        }

        @Bean
        public TextSerializer textSerializer(){
            return new TextSerializer();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `JsonFormatVisitable` and where does it come from?

Comment: It's the interface of JsonSerializer.